# Relative image size in table cell

Tags: html, css

I want my table row to be 100% of the screen width and 50px high.  If my table only has a paragraph element in it then it sizes appropriately.  If the table has an image in it then the row expands to the size of the image.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o70xtmov/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=bad-size" alt="project-icon" title=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>good-size</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

table:first-of-type {
    background-color: #666666;
}

table:last-of-type {
    background-color: #888888;
}

tr {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}

img {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: The row is using full width in the fiddle you provided. What is the problem?

Comment: you have img height 100%. which will give you the 100% of the img file.  Try setting a max-height of 50px for the img.

Comment: I would like my image to scale as a percentage of the parent.  In the actual application not every row has a height of 50px (e.g. the selected row increases in size) and it is a pain to have to resize the image every time as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the problem of you're setting the height to the `tr` tag? and that doesn't work. How about this? The `td` will get resized if the content is taller.

http://jsfiddle.net/bwvvvn0y/

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    background: #888;
}

td {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why but you are right.  Setting the px height on the td and not the tr works.  This makes no sense to me.

Setting the image height was just a copy/paste error, in the actual application I want the image to be 80% of the height of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
img {
    height:50px;
    width:auto;
}
```

(Tested this and it worked)

Comment: Yes, but, as per my comment on the original question.  I would like to specify the image height relative to the row height.  This is because the row height changes and I don't want to always have to change the image height.

Comment: Yes, I saw that as soon as I submitted my answer. Unfortunately, it was not there yet when I read the question. Cheers!